# IE 8 not working with jQuery.parseXML

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery 1.9.1. It works fine in Chrome, but Ie 8, i get error:  "invalid xml". 
It seems IE 6-8 has problems with dataType: xml.  Jquery.parseXML is not working on ie-6-8.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "faculty.xml",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(xml) { parseXmlx(xml); },
        error: function(e) { alert(e) }
    });
    $("#output").append("<p>Loading full-time faculty...</p>");
});

function parseXmlx(xml) {
    $("#output").empty();
    // alert(xml);
    var $xml = $(jQuery.parseXML(xml));
    // find every Tutorial and print the author
}



<person>
<name>test</name>
</person>
```

error:

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Timestamp: Wed, 19 Jun 2013 17:42:26 UTC


Message: Invalid XML: <person>
<name>Test</name>
</person>

Line: 507
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: jquery-1.9.1.js
```

Comment: What does `faculty.xml` look like?

Comment: Is your XML valid? Just because it works in chrome doesn't mean it's valid.

Comment: You can try to make sure your xml is valid by validating it here. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: Looks like my xml is valid.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019015/jquery-xml-parse-with-check-for-ie8-not-working

Comment: I went to that page already, appreantly IE 6-8 crap out on dataytpe XML. It keeps failing for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the problem causing the issue, but it's good practise to add following line as the first line of your XML file. (don't have access to IE8 to test this)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

you could also try forcing the headers to make sure these are correct:

change

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "faculty.xml",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(xml) { parseXmlx(xml); },
    error: function(e) { alert(e) }
});
```

to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "faculty.xml",
    dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text" : "xml",
    accepts: {
         xml: "text/xml",
         text: "text/xml"
    },
    success: function(xml) { parseXmlx(xml); },
    error: function(e) { alert(e) }
});
```

(cfr. [IE9 refuses to process XML response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746515/ie9-refuses-to-process-xml-response) )

Comment: hmm you also seem to have an empty line at the end of the xml, could you remove that as well (also make sure that the person tag is under the <?xml ... ?> lin

Comment: I deleted the empty line and added the ?xml but error still persists.

Comment: you could try forcing headers in your ajax request aswell (i'll edit my answer)